# Recursive parse JSON tree in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to display the comments of reddit posts using react native. Since the returned JSON from the API is always a nested number of comments I guess the best way to parse the JSON is to use recursion.
To get the comments for a post in a subreddit the following url can be use and I've linked an example.

[`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}/comments/${postId}.json`](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/3wrswc.json)

Next step I'm using a recursive function to move through the JSON tree and find any object that has a `body` property and push it in to an array.

```
parseComments(comments, i, j) {
    for (let property in comments) {
      if (comments.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        if (property === "replies") {
          this.parseComments(comments[property], i, j);
        } else if (typeof comments[property] === "object") {
          if (comments[property] != null) {
            if (comments[property].body != undefined) {
              this.setState(prevState => ({
                commentStrings: [...prevState.commentStrings,
                  ".".repeat(j) + comments[property].body
                ]
              }));
              j += 1;
            }
            this.parseComments(comments[property], i, j);
          }
        }
      } 
    }
  }
```

I'm using [Expo](https://expo.io/) to debug and test the code on my phone but when the code enters the recursive function it just freezes there.

Is there a CPU or Memory limitation that causes this and what is the best way to display the comments in this example JSON.

Comment: It seems I misinterpreted your question. You have a JSON object, not a string, and want to find something inside it?

Comment: yes exactly, I have a nested JSON object which can random number of children. I'm trying to find a certain property and render the found values but the code freezes.

Comment: If an object has a property called `body` do you need to push it's children to the array too, but separately?

Comment: no if a property replies or children exists I need to parse that object and the root object with reply or children will have a body property which is a string and I need to push that to an array.